# How to setup Appium on MAC with Java for iPhone Automation?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, automated-tests, appium

I am new to the world of Software Test Automation. I have worked earlier as a developer. I have successfully setup and used the Appium for Android apps testing with Java environment on Windows, Mac Mini and Linux. Can anyone please help me with setup of appium for iOS testing? My environment is as follows.

1) Mac Mini (An old machine)
2) Java
3) iPhone

Any link to the step-by-step video tutorial and/or useful webpage will be much appreciated. I will appreciate even more if one could provide me the steps in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not a site where you ask for tutorials - this is a place where you provide your programming problem and users try to solve it together.

Secondly, I do not understand how can You not understand how to work with Appium for iOS if you have already experience with Android with Appium? Everything is the same except the driver which will be used to interact with (in this case `IOSDriver(address, capabilities)`).